# curl script for twilio API

Tags: shell, twilio

```
curl -X POST "https://studio.twilio.com/v1/Flows/xxx/Engagements" -d "To=$arrayIWant" -d "From=$mytwilionumber" -u authKeyXXX:authIDxxx
```

I'm looking to write a shell script to pull a number from the $arrayIwant .txt file and execute the curl request to that number. I have a txt file with a list of phone numbers that I would like to iterate through and send multiple curl requests with a script.